# Can I run a DBus interface (org.freedekstop) methods on headless ubuntu server?

Tags: server

I am trying to switch OS to CentOS, however the CentOS installation uses [org.freedesktop.NetworkManager](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/unstable/gdbus-org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.html)
which seems to return too many network devices. So I would like to try running `org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.GetDevices()` form my ubuntu server and see what it returns. How can I do this?

Running: Ubuntu server 18.4

Comment: You have given no release details, but modern Ubuntu servers don't use NetworkManager (it is used however by Ubuntu Desktop).

Comment: @guiverc sorry, updated which OS I am using.

Comment: Those don't look like commands, but functions to be used in source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a DBus interface, documented [here](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/unstable/gdbus-org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.html)

Here how you can call that method:

```
$ gdbus call --system \
--dest org.freedesktop.NetworkManager \
--object-path /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager \
--method org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.GetDevices

([objectpath '/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1', '/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2', '/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3'],)
```